# Starting Activity on condition produces a flicker on screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a UI-less `MainActivity`, which holds certain logic to determine if the user is already logged in or not. If the user is logged in, I am starting `HomeActivity` and if not, then `LoginActivity`. Even though the logic is working fine, I am seeing that the `MainActivity` does start for a brief while before switching to desired activity. Is there any way to avoid bringing up `MainActivity` altogether as it causes an annoying flicker ?

Here is my code (omitting the logic) -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (condition) {
            intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        }

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

This is what I have in my android manifest -

```
    <activity
        android:name="org.step.main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Are you trying in your device or in the emulator?

Comment: I am trying on the device.

Comment: Definitely the problem is not here. Not in that code. Except that the `condition` is very very heavy to compute.

Comment: Anyways, can you avoid the no-UI solution? Try to put the HomeActivity code in Main Activity and do the logic there, as you're doing it now, and if the user is not logged in then you finish actual and you start the LoginActivity.

Comment: The condition fetches a key-value pair from sharedpreferences and assigns them to a local variable, if present.

Comment: @joaquin Ya, I tried it earlier, by launching LoginActivity first and then checking the condition, and if true then switching to HomeActivity. But, same result occurred. As LoginActivity had a UI, so I thought of adding the logic to a UI-less activity like above. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Then the problem is in your device. Try your app in an emulator or in another device, please

Comment: was your device rooted? I am experiencing the same behavior, but only on rooted devices and emulators.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION on the intent

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

and/or call `overridePendingTransition(0, 0)` after calling finish()

You could also replace the activities with Fragments - have the MainActivity with a fullscreen scontainer that you replace with a login Fragment or a Home Fragment.

Comment: So, I added the flag and overridePendingTransition as you mentioned and  it worked fine. Thanks for the help.